# How would I animate a sprite to flash 2 different colors on screen in JavaScript, with this code? Or rather how would I fix it?

Tags: javascript, animation, modulo

I have been trying to animate essentially a title screen from a sprite sheet. I have the sprite sheet loaded in, but I can't seem to figure out why the animation isn't happening. I have an update function that requires no parameters to run:

```
function update(){
     menu.update
}
```

I also have `let frames = 0` at the beginning of my code.
My issue is when drawing the animation or something along those lines. It draws the 0th frame from animation but not the 1st frame. I have tried putting the animator under the 'if' statement, but after a few attempts, I couldn't get it to stop asking for parameters and/or expressions. (I tried some arrow functions, but I'm not used to using them so I don't know if what I did was right or wrong.)

```
const menu = {
    animation : [
        {sX: 27, sY: 295},
        {sX: 27, sY: 399},
    ],
    x : cvs.width/2 - 118/2,
    y : 100,
    w : 118,
    h : 84,

    frame : 0,


     // Animator
     update : function(){
         // Incrementation % incrementation period (speed)
        this.frame += frames%5 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        // Iteration of animation--draws 0 then 1 then 0....       
        this.frame = this.frame%this.animation.lenghth;

    },



    draw : function(){
        let animCounter = this.animation[this.frame];

        if(status.current == status.Start){

            ctx.drawImage(sprite, animCounter.sX, animCounter.sY, this.w, this.h, this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
        }
    },

   
}
```

I am pretty sure the problem lies in the 'if' statement, I can get this to work with another sprite on this sprite sheet; it doesn't have an 'if' statement, but everything else except for the source position and such, are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be due to a simple typo:

```
this.frame = this.frame%this.animation.lenghth;
```

should read:

```
this.frame = this.frame%this.animation.length; // removed the "h"
```

Here's a demo with an alternating hippo :-)

```js
var sprite = document.getElementById('source');
var width = 600,
  height = 600,
  cvs = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0],
  ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
cvs.width = width;
cvs.height = height;

const menu = {
  animation: [{
      sX: 27,
      sY: 295
    },
    {
      sX: 27,
      sY: 399
    },
  ],
  x: cvs.width / 2 - 118 / 2,
  y: 100,
  w: 118,
  h: 84,

  frame: 0,
  frames: 0,

  // Animator
  update: function() {
    // Incrementation % incrementation period (speed)
    this.frame += this.frames % 5 == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    // Iteration of animation--draws 0 then 1 then 0....       
    this.frame = this.frame % this.animation.length;

        this.draw();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      menu.update();
    }, 300);
  },

  draw: function() {
    let animCounter = this.animation[this.frame];
    //if (status.current == status.Start) {

      ctx.drawImage(sprite, animCounter.sX, animCounter.sY);
    //}
  }

}
menu.update();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<img id="source"
       src="https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/5397/rhino.jpg"
       width="300" height="227" style="display:none;">
```